# Parsing Complicated JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization":"bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImIzNzkwODExLWIxM2QtNDYxZS04MWE0LWFmOTI3YjRjNDQxNiIsImlzcyI6IkNlcnRpZnkiLCJhdWQiOiJiMzc5MDgxMS1iMTNkLTQ2MWUtODFhNC1hZjkyN2I0YzQ0MTYifQ.Akuc-_By-GcheZUls2HokIUWDaMha8K_hEAnEc9K3qk"}
url = "https://ap.certify.com/purchasingapi/api/invoices?req.download=Downloaded&req.accountReview=Approved&req.after=01%2F01%2F2021&req.before=12%2F31%2F2021&req.size=1000&req.page=1&req.sort=TransactionDate"
result = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
result.text


result.json()['Result']

index0 = result.json()['Result']['Results'][0]


def dict2df(list):
    dict = {}
    for i in list:
        dict[i] = list[i]
    return pd.DataFrame([dict])


df1 = dict2df(index0)

df2 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1.to_json(orient = 'records')))
```

After all, I have a dataframe df2 which has these columns:

```
df2.columns

#Index(['InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceDate', 'InvoiceEnterDate', 'Comment',
#       'PostingDate', 'Voided', 'CurrencyId',
#       'CustomCurrencyConversionRateToUsd', 'ManualCheck', 'IsManualCheck',
#       'DueDate', 'Paid', 'Details', 'CreditCardCharge', 'Total',
#       'Attachments', 'Identifier', 'User.ErpId', 'User.FirstName',
#       'User.LastName', 'User.Identifier', 'Vendor.Name', 'Vendor.Address1',
#       'Vendor.Address2', 'Vendor.City', 'Vendor.State', 'Vendor.Zip',
#       'Vendor.Country', 'Vendor.Phone', 'Vendor.Fax', 'Vendor.AccountNumber',
#       'Vendor.ErpId', 'Vendor.Term', 'Vendor.GLAccount', 'Vendor.Identifier'],
#      dtype='object')
```

The problem is. The columns: 'Details' & 'Attachments' are not un-nested yet.
These:

```
df2.explode('Details')
df2.explode('Attachments')
```

does not help me to solve yet. Anyone has the solution? Many thanks

Comment: What is your question? You don't say anything about why output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to completely flatten the dictionary:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImIzNzkwODExLWIxM2QtNDYxZS04MWE0LWFmOTI3YjRjNDQxNiIsImlzcyI6IkNlcnRpZnkiLCJhdWQiOiJiMzc5MDgxMS1iMTNkLTQ2MWUtODFhNC1hZjkyN2I0YzQ0MTYifQ.Akuc-_By-GcheZUls2HokIUWDaMha8K_hEAnEc9K3qk",
}
url = "https://ap.certify.com/purchasingapi/api/invoices?req.download=Downloaded&req.accountReview=Approved&req.after=01%2F01%2F2021&req.before=12%2F31%2F2021&req.size=1000&req.page=1&req.sort=TransactionDate"
result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)


def flatten(d, path=""):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from flatten(v, (path + "_" + k).strip("_"))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if len(d) == 1:
            yield from flatten(d[0], path)
        else:
            for i, v in enumerate(d):
                yield from flatten(v, (path + "_" + str(i)).strip("_"))
    else:
        yield path, d


out = []
for r in result.json()["Result"]["Results"]:
    out.append(dict(flatten(r)))

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: OMG it's so kind of you. Thank you so much <3